# Interpretation of "as"

Tags: comparison, adjuncts

> The word "challenging", as used in this context, means "demanding".

Does the word "as" mean "when" or "in such way"？  Thank you.

Comment: 'In the way that it is being used in this context'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. It means something like "how", or "in that way".

For example you could say:

- "This product works just as seen on television!"  (the same way we
  saw it work there)
- "He can't be trusted, as I told you."  (just like
  I told you, he cannot be trusted)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

It is a shortened way of saying: "such as it is" or "such as is".